# Ctrl + F5 does not refresh all content

Tags: caching, browser

on my admin site I have created script for cropping images. After cropping, I update url of image cropped with ?v=timestamp, so everything is ok. But after I leave page, and come back, there's photo without version loaded and is againg the same.

Photo is cropped OK. When i add version change, browser refresh image, problem is, I'm not able to clear image cache, even if I use Control + F5.

Is it possible there is some server side caching? How to find out?

Comment: What CMS you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes happens with javascript and images. Use cache clear before refreshing page.
in firfox there are plugin also available, which can clear cache by one click only.
So before refresh page,just click that button to clear cache.

Comment: Well, that's nice, I know how to refresh it, but I'm looking for solution that will help to my customers too

Comment: Does that help?
<script src="test.js?random=<?php echo uniqid(); ?>"></script>
and
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>